# I want to animate the trajectory of a ball (really just a circle) using Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, projectile, matplotlib-animation

I want to animate the trajectory of a circle (ball) defined by y = -t^2 + 11t - 18. Basically it would just be bouncing up and down (i.e. no change in x). Its intercepts are (2,0) and (9,0) so the animation should start at time t = 2 as it leaves the ground and end at time t = 9 as it returns to the ground. I am also hoping that a running display of the time could also be included in the animation. So basically between times t=0 and t=2, the ball would just be on the ground. This is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to make sense. I'm not sure whether the animation is just going too fast.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(3, 3)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 15))
patch = plt.Circle((5, 0), 0.2, fc='r')

def init():
    patch.center = (5, 0)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = 0 * i+5
    y = - i**2 + 11 * i - 18
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=3600, 
                               interval=1,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the ball at x = 5

Comment: It is going too fast. If you increase the interval to 100 (i.e. 100 ms), everything looks fine.